# Make Excel PivotTable connect to multiple Access DBs to look up data

Tags: excel, ms-access, connection, pivot-table, lookup

I need a good advise here.

I am trying to make an `Excel reporting dashboard` that is using `PivotTable / Sliders`, so people can filter on data. However, I have 8 `Access` DBs from a hundred megs to 1.x GB where my data is in - meaning that I cannot combine them as there is a limit of 2 GB in `Access`.

What I would like to do, is to make my `Excel PivotTable` look up data in all 8 of the `Access` DBs. For instance, I want to look up `manufacturer = 'ABC'`, then it should return all data from the 8 DBs where `manufacturer = 'ABC'`.

I have been reading/looking at linking the 8 DBs in Access (in a master "lookup" Access DB) and then using a `SQL query Union All` to combine them. However, I do not know if this is actually possible (I have not made it work yet), or if there is a better way. All these files are stored on a shared drive.

** EDIT
The data is stored in CSV files to start off with.
All the DBs contain the same amount of tables and headers.

Comment: If you want to consolidate your 8 DBs, but can't because of Access file size limit, I suggest to move your data to a server database (SQL Server, MySQL, ...). What you plan to do sounds like a nightmare to implement and maintain.

Comment: If the data is stored in CSV files, then why are the Access databases so huge? Are they storing duplicates of the source data, and if so, why?

Comment: *All the DBs contain the same amount of tables and headers.* - even more reason to put them into a single server database.

Comment: @Andre thanks for your comments. Would you just create an SQL DB in Mgmt studio and then host it somewhere locally on our network? If so, how would be the easiest to maintain the DB?

Comment: Hi @ErikvonAsmuth I have just loaded a 241MB CSV file into Access, which made the Access DB size to 588 MB. I do not know, why they are so huge, maybe due to the way Access is built? There are no duplicates.

Comment: Well, my question is more, why aren't you importing into a linked table? That way the size shouldn't increase that much.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I tried that but then my PivotTable in Excel says that there are no existing tables. My Access file is like 500 kb when linking to a CSV file.

Comment: Yes, but that is easily avoided by adding a query that's just `SELECT * FROM MyImportedTable` (where MyImportedTable is the name of your imported .csv).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth how do I do that? When I have my Create PivotTable box, I select "Use an external data source", click on "Choose Connection..." and when I find it there and click open, it says no existing tables. When I press "OK", it says "Data Source reference is not valid."

Comment: You need to add the query to the Access database, not the Excel file. Then, Excel should see 1 view in the Access database (your query), and you should be able to use that.